# Asp Core добавление нового способа регистрации с использованием Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Доброго дня,
Возник вопрос, имею WebApplication на AspNetCore 1.1.0 с реализованной классической моделью Identity, в классической реализации при регистрации пользователя используются email / password, мне необходимо реализовать возможность регистрации также и по CodeNumber (числовая последовательность длиной 15 символов) в качестве login name, и pin code (числовая комбинация из 4 символов) в качестве пароля.

При этом хранение CodeNumber и PinСode осуществляется в отдельной (не связанной с создаваемой Identity) таблице.

Подскажите пожалуйста каким способом этого можно достичь в Asp .Net Core ?
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: про авторизации и аутентификации можете читать тут https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/12.1.php

Comment: Спасибо, данные материалы смотрел, в них нет информации по теме

Comment: Про аутентификацию вам правильно ответили, могу разве что добавить, что можно использовать кастомную  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/317sza4k.aspx авторизацию, а если у вас вопрос именно по **identityserver4** то спрашивать нужно по функционалу identityserver4.

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема? Сделать поле email необязательным и добавить поле login?

Comment: Обновил текст вопроса

Comment: Если не секрет  - где вы собираетесь хранить эту таблицу ? И в каком виде её представляете ?